# django - is there an addon/lib etc that will filter out urls entered?

Tags: python, django

if i'm using django, and a user submits, say, a comment to my website - what is the best way (or what ways are there?) to programatically "alert" that a url has been submitted, and then do something to that url?

Either  "fix" it so it isn't clickable, or "flag" it so i review the comment before approving, or emailing me saying "someone submitted a comment"  - or, you know what, provide a hook so i can do something?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect a function to **[post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)**
2. For every value in `instance.__dict__`, **check for presence of a url**
3. If a url is present, [send an email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs/) or **do what you want**

For example:

```
from django.db.models import signals

def check_for_url(sender, instance, created, kwargs**):
    for value in instance.__dict__.values():
        if 'http://' in value:
            # do want you want
post_save.connect(check_for_url)
```

Since your question isn't precise, that should give you some starters, you should of course refine it according to your specific needs.